# weird problem echoing array (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Ok so I have the following code. I'm trying to output some xml so that it can be read with jQuery, but for whatever reason, when I try to add an element in the array to a variable, it just turns the variable to 0. I did a print_r() on the array, and it's normal.

**Code**

```
if ($content == "tables") {
    $result = mysql_query("show tables");
$xml = "<tables>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
        echo "<br />";
        $xml += "<table>" . $row['Tables_in_blog'] . "</table>";
    }
    //header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $xml;
}
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [Tables_in_blog] => post )
Array ( [Tables_in_blog] => posts )
0
```

Does anyone know why it would do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$xml += "<table>" . $row['Tables_in_blog'] . "</table>";
```

That's the offender. Try concatenation:

```
$xml .= "<table>" . $row['Tables_in_blog'] . "</table>";
```

You mistakenly used `+=` instead of `.=` for concatenation. This triggered PHP to convert the values to numbers (resulting in `0`) and adding them.